# How to get object entries from nlohmann json

Tags: c++, json

I've tried to search how to get object entries from JSON using JSON for Modern C++, but I couldn't find and answer.

I have JSON like this:

```json
{
  "Command": "cmd",
  "Data": {"time": 200, "type":1},
  /* ... */
}
```

And I want to ask how to get object with key `Data`, how to store it and how to access its elements (count of elements and keys in data can change depending on command).

Comment: In this case, `Data` is an object, not an array

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can read a json file into a json object like that:

```
std::ifstream jsonFile("commands.json");
nlohmann::json commands;
jsonFile >> commands;
```

To retrieve the "Data" object (and print the number of elements it contains):

```
nlohmann::json data = commands["Data"];
std::cout << "Number of items in Data: " << data.size() << std::endl;
```

And finally to loop over all keys and values in "Data":

```
for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << it.key() << ": " << it.value() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is very useful for me, but is there in this library function to copy obiect with key "data" to other nlohmann::json object. (Sorry if it is silly question, but I'm using this library for first time).

Comment: You're welcome.
Yes, of course this is possible. If "otherObject" is your json object you want to copy "data" to, simply use otherObject["data"] = data;

Comment: But can i just make object json and do object = otherObject['data']? And thank you for help.

Comment: With `nlohmann::json object = otherObject["data"];`, "object" will still reference to to the original data. If you want to copy it, use `nlohmann::json copy; copy["data"] = otherObject["data"];`

Comment: Ok, so in object, there will be only array of objects from josn where key is "data", without Commant etc. ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If this was helpful, you should accept the answer and ask new, specific questions when needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my problem